# How do I plot my country map with weather data stations?

Tags: curated-data, geography

I've tried this code, but I can't plot the coordinates in my country map.

```
Weather = {"Ulaanbaatar", "Erdenet"}  

stationtocoordinate = Map[# -> WeatherData[#, "Coordinates"] &, Weather]
```

---

`allWeatherStations = WeatherData[];
fullformStations = FullForm /@ allWeatherStations;
Tally[StringLength /@ fullformStations[[All, 1, 2]]]` . This code not working. Why?

Comment: Mongolia`CountryData["Mongolia", "Shape"]`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica Stack exchange!  Use the up/down arrows to upvote an answer and the tick mark to accept an answer you deem correct. I've also edited your code - it was missing a definition for Weather and the Map was missing a `]` at the end.    Also note its good Mathematica practise NOT to use Capitalised variable names as you may inadvertently collide with a named Mathematica function.

Answer (score 14):

There is an example of what I think you are trying to do at the end of `WeatherData` help page, but its a little hard to read.  However - here's what I think you want.

```
(* Function to  Get a list consisting of {CityName, Temp, Co-ords} 
given a Countries weather station, note we get the 1st 
nearest weather station to the city *)

weatherdata[cityname_] := {cityname, WeatherData[#, "Temperature"], 
 WeatherData[#, "Coordinates"]} & /@ WeatherData[{cityname, 1}];

(* Get Names for all Cities *)

cities = CityData[#, "Name"] & /@ CityData[{All, "Mongolia"}];

(*  Get the weather and weather station co-ordinates for the list of 
cities  (the Drop is a kludge to remove the incorrect city "Moron") 
from the weather data *)

wdata = Drop[weatherdata[#] & /@ cities, 9];

(*  Plot the list of city weather stations on a map using GeoPosition to 
correctly plot the co-ordinates*)

GeoGraphics[{Point[GeoPosition[wdata[[All, 1, 3]]]], 
Polygon[Entity["Country", "Mongolia"]], GeoRange -> "Country"}]
```

[image]

I'll leave it as an exercise to change the points to something that changes depending on the temperature.  i.e. a disc that changes colour/radius.  There are some good examples in the `GeoGraphics` help.

Answer (score 9):

`WeatherData` can be told to give you all the weather stations it knows about, but there's more than one type of weather station (and duplicates!):

```
allWeatherStations = WeatherData[];
fullformStations = FullForm /@ allWeatherStations;
Tally[StringLength /@ fullformStations[[All, 1, 2]]]
(*{{4, 6919}, {5, 10306}, {8, 4697}}*)
```

Looking at the documentation, I find the "WMO*" stations seem to be the interesting, and reliable ones. I extract these and find their corrdinates:

```
wmoWeatherStations = Cases[fullformStations[[All, 1, 2]], a_ /; StringLength[a] == 8];
wmoStationsPositions = 
  GeoPosition[WeatherData[#, "Coordinates"]] & /@ wmoWeatherStations;
```

Using `GeoWithinQ` I find those stations within Mongolia and then use `Pick` to include these in `GeoGraphics`

```
wmoMongolia = GeoWithinQ[Entity["Country", "Mongolia"], wmoStationsPositions];
GeoGraphics[GeoMarker[Pick[wmoStationsPositions, wmoMongolia]], 
 GeoRange -> Entity["Country", "Mongolia"]]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, that usage of `FullForm` to get the entities doesn't appear to be documented.  Does it work on all the curated data functions?

Comment: It's a cheat to easily get the name of the weather station without having to call a paclet for a property of the Entity. All Entities can be converted into this StandardForm representation of the Entity.

Comment: I meant InputForm.