# StringLength function

Tags: functions

`allWeatherStations = WeatherData[];
fullformStations = FullForm /@ allWeatherStations;
Tally[StringLength /@ fullformStations[[All, 1, 2]]]`.
This code not working. Why not working stringlength function.

Comment: Regarding this code snippet, [you have asked](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/80774/7167) the member who originally posted the code for clarification, and you [spammed your own question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/80915/7167) with an answer that is a question.  Asking another question about the same exact topic is frowned upon here. If @MartinJohnHadly chooses to do so, they will respond.

Comment: For what it's worth `WeatherData[]` without arguments runs for an exceedingly long time (about 5 minutes on my computer) before reporting out the entities.  I do have a a slow internet connection.  Try each line in a separate cell without the output suppression (; at the end of the line) and see where precisely the problem is.  Outside of the long delay in the first line, the code works.

Comment: This code works fine here.  I would suspect the internet connection.